# How to insert the data into Azure Cosmos DB from external file using PowerShell Script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I have a PowerShell script for creating database and collection inside Azure Cosmos DB and I am able to insert some dummy records inside collection by using the below PowerShell script.

```
    #region Parameters

$clientId= "< Replace with your clientId >"
$clientSecret= "< Replae with you clientsecret >"
$subscriptionName= "< Replace with your subscription name>"
$tenantId= "< Replace with your tenant Id>"
$resourceGroupName= "Demo"
$connectionString='< Replace wtih Cosmos DB Connection String >'
$cosmosDBAccounts= @('demo-account-01')
#$accountName='demo-account-01'
$databaseName='demo-db-01'
$collectionName='demo-collection-01'
$partitionkey= 'demo'

#endregion

#region Login into Azure using Interactive Mode or Service Principal details

# sign in
Write-Host "Logging in...";

#Connect-AzAccount 
$securePassword = $clientSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $clientId, $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId

#Set the current azure subscription
Select-AzSubscription  -subscription $subscriptionName

#endregion

#region Create Collection and insert some data into it

foreach($cosmosDBAccount in $cosmosDBAccounts){

    $cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDbAccount -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName    
    New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $databaseName
    New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $collectionName -PartitionKey $partitionkey -OfferThroughput 2500 -Database $databaseName

0..9 | Foreach-Object {

$document = @"
{
         "id": "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())",
         "name": "pradeep",         
         "demo": "XYZ"  
}
"@

New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $collectionName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "XYZ"

}
}

#endregion
```

But I want to insert the records into Azure Cosmos DB from external file instead of putting the JSON data directly inside PowerShell script.

So, can anyone suggest me how to insert the data into Azure Cosmos DB from external file.

Comment: Could you provide the file sample? Is it a `.json` file?

Comment: Does the residence of the external files stable? Such as Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: @Joy, It is a .json file only.

Comment: Right now the .json file is located in my local machine only.

Comment: What the content in the file? Could you provide a sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the code snippet to where you need, it will create the documents of the `.json` file in the collection.

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\cosmos.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDbAccount -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName

foreach($item in $json){
    $document = $item | ConvertTo-Json | Out-String
    New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $collectionName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey "XYZ"

}
```

My `.json` file:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "pradeep",
    "demo": "XYZ"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "pradeep12",
    "demo": "XYZ"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "pradeep123",
    "demo": "XYZ"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "pradeep1234",
    "demo": "XYZ"
}]
```

**Result**:

[image]

**Check in the portal**:

[image]